# window.addEventListener('load') works fine on PC but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, addeventlistener

I have developed react website which works as expected on PC but not on Mobile.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll); // this fire works fine
    window.addEventListener('load', this.themeSet); // this event does not fired in Mobile
 }
```

I added a feature to set theme when the site load for the first time .The load event fires on **PC** but not on **mobile** coz whenever i try to open my website in mobile it does not load the theme correctly. Also I checked this by added alert('works') in the `themeSet` function and yes it execute in **Pc** but not on **mobile**.

I am sure that  `window.addEventListener('load', this.themeSet);` is not fired on Mobile but works on PC . this is weird I don't know why

Note: `window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);` works completely okay on both devices laptop and mobile.

I hope i'll get an answer
Thank you in Advance .

Here is site I created with react : https://notse.dev/

You can see it remembers which theme you selected in PC even if you reload.

But on Mobile when you reload it just reset to dark theme .

Comment: maybe the event fires, but the function doesn't run

Comment: the function runs i mentioned that i added alert in the function it runs in PC but not in mobile. only in Mobile it does not work

Comment: there's no `alert`

Comment: i removed it after i test it and i test it locally believe me I have tried everything

Comment: OK, so which **mobile** ... android? ios? both? other?

Comment: I test with all smart devices like IPAD , ANDROID (SAMSUNG), the load event does not work in any mobile devices.

Comment: I just tried on android and iphone - window load event definitely fires `window.addEventListener('load', () => alert('loaded'))`

Comment: probably something in `this.themeSet` that isn't working for mobiles

Comment: after some research I add a code 

if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      this.themeSet()
      console.log('readySate')
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('load', this.themeSet);
      console.log('event here')
    }

now its working on mobile too 
i guess before it was loading already in a server thats why its not working in mobile but exaclty i don't know what happened it just works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Some research I found a code related to my problem and it works i guess the reason would be that load event is already fired in server even though the Dom did not load only when i load my site from a mobile I don't know exactly why it works for PC without eror but yeah i guess this could be the reason.

The code that works for mobile is this:

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      this.themeSet()
      console.log('readySate')
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('load', this.themeSet);
      console.log('event here')
    }
```